# Get the system name with lookup field

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, powershell

I would like to automate site creations based on templates. I would like to use a list that, among other things, reads the possible templates from the Solution Gallery with lookup column and displays the system name that I can later use in my scripts. Can I change the lookup somehow to return the system name of the template?

Answer (score 0):

We have implemented the auto site creation with Nintex workflow.it would be easy we have so many options with nintex or try with sharepoint designer workflow.

hope this will help you!

santhosh durgam